# Cannot paste from xlsx to xlsm

Tags: excel, vba

The strangest thing is happening to me. I have an xlsm workbook with a number of macros at all levels (general, worksheet, workbook). All works as expected with it, but if I try to copy some cells from an xlsx workbook and paste them into my xlsm workbook, the `Paste` option is grayed out. Ctrl-V also doesn't paste. I tried

```
application.commandbars("cell").reset
```

in the Immediate window. That didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: There can be couple of reasons for this `1` A code in your xlsm file is clearing of the clipboard. Check if there is any code in the sheet or the thisworkbook code area which may be clearing of the clipboard. `2` The workbook structure or the worksheet is protected `3` Your workbook is corrupt and you may have to do some re-building? What happens when you try to paste into a new workbook?

Comment: It was number `1`. The workbook module had `Application.Calculate` in it. If you want the points, paste your comment into an answer and I'll give them to you. Thanks for your direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be few reasons for this

1. A code in your xlsm file is clearing of the clipboard. Check if there is any code in the sheet or the thisworkbook code area which may be clearing off the clipboard.
2. The workbook structure or the worksheet is protected
3. Your workbook is corrupt and you may have to do some re-building? What happens when you try to paste into a new workbook?